# getting the first date when record was created

Tags: sql

I have a query where I need to display the user that first created a record of customer information.  See my query below:

```
 select CustID, Title, Firstname, Surname, IDNumber, min(ModifyDate) as ModDate, sUsername
from Customers
where StatusCode = 'PI'
group by CustlD,Title,Firstname,Surname,IDNumber,sUsername
```

My result is displayed below:

```
1    MR    CHARL    8607295    2012-10-23 14:20:31.407   User1
1    MR    CHARL    8607295    2012-10-24 12:36:09.023   User2
2    MISS  XABA     8307297    2012-10-23 14:23:08.593   User1
2    MISS  XABA     8307297    2012-10-24 14:57:29.603   User2
```

I only need the first record and the 3rd record.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What database? MySQL/Oracle/SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select CustID, c1.Title, Firstname, Surname, IDNumber, ModifyDate as ModDate, sUsername
from Customers  c
where StatusCode = 'PI' and c.ModifyDate = (SELECT TOP 1 ModifyDate FROM Customers c_ WHERE c_.CustID = c.CustID ORDER BY ModifyDate ASC)
```

UPDATE:

```
select CustID, Firstname, Surname, IDNumber, ModifyDate as ModDate, sUsername
from dbo.test32  c
where c.ModifyDate = (SELECT TOP 1 ModifyDate
                      FROM (
                            SELECT CustID, ModifyDate, CASE WHEN sUserName = 'User1' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sUserName ORDER BY ModifyDate ASC) ELSE 2 END AS sn
                            FROM dbo.test32
                            ) c_
                      WHERE c_.sn > 1 AND c_.CustID = c.CustID ORDER BY ModifyDate ASC)
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I actually made a mistake, I need the second record per customerID.  How do I get the second record?

Comment: @user1668123 I don't absolutely understand. 2 and 3 records?

Comment: The data is automatically loaded to the system so the first user is user 1.  What I need is the user record that modified the information after it was loaded.  The first modified by will always be user 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on a database system that supports `ROW_NUMBER()` (modern versions of Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc):

```
select CustID, Title, Firstname, Surname, IDNumber, ModifyDate, sUsername
from (
   select
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY CustID
          ORDER BY ModifyDate) rn
   from Customers) c
where StatusCode = 'PI' and rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
   c1.CustID, 
   c1.Title, 
   c1.Firstname, 
   c1.Surname, 
   c1.IDNumber, 
   c2.ModDate, 
    c1.sUsername
FROM Customers c1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CustID, min(ModifyDate) AS ModDate
    FROM Customers
    GROUP BY CustID
) c2 ON c1.CustID = c2.custID AND c1.ModifyDate = c2.ModDate
WHERE c1.StatusCode = 'PI'
```

However, if you are using SQL-Server then you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` to do this as in the [@Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13134756/722783).